# ReferenceError: timbreController is not defined

Tags: nodejs, vue.js

Estoy intentando generar codigo nodejs, pero me manda el siguiente error

```
module.exports = {
oninit : function (vnode) { 
  this.ctx = new timbreController(vnode.attrs); 
},
view : function (vnode) { 
  return facturaView(this.ctx) 
   }
};

function timbreController(Params) {
var ctx = this;
var search = m.prop('');
console.log(location);
}
function facturaView(ctx){
console.log(ctx);
}
```

y me arroja el siguient error

> "ReferenceError: timbreController is not defined
>       at eval (eval at view etc.......

Comment: puedes poner el error completo? y cuando te pasa ?

Answer (score 0):

La función **timbreController** esta definida fuera del modulo(el que exportas), se encuentran en diferentes contextos y por eso no la encuentra como definida, podrías crearla dentro del modulo si no causa problemas la captura del `this` que realizas.